# operator does not exist: json = json ef core

Tags: postgresql, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am using efcore 5+ and Postgresql in my project , I have json property in my dataset as

```
    [Column("servicesIncluded", TypeName ="json")]
    public object ServicesIncluded { get; set; }
```

When I try to compare this value in join with some other table like:

```
         var query = await (from costItemTemplate in _shipContext.CostItemTemplates
                           join itemDetails in _shipContext.CostTemplateDetails
                           on costItemTemplate.TemplateId equals itemDetails.CostItemTemplateId
                           where costItemTemplate.ShipmentType == quote.ShipmentType &&
                                 costItemTemplate.TemplatePort.Contains(quote.FromLocation) &&
                                 costItemTemplate.ServicesIncluded == quote.AdditionalService
                           select itemDetails).ToListAsync();
```

I get Error that **operator does not exist: json = json**

```
Npgsql.PostgresException (0x80004005): 42883: operator does not exist: json = json
```

I have tried to Serialize objects in ef core LINQ query but again that serialization is not supported in db .

**Is there any way to compare these both (objects/json)** columns?

Comment: Have you tried to make this column as `string`?

Comment: Cant make changes in db

Comment: Which DB change? Just change type `object`to `string`.